# Calculate total rainfall for each day in a list

Tags: python-3.x

The question states:
Write a function print_daily_totals(rainfalls) that prints the total rainfall for each day of rainfall values given. The parameter rainfalls is a list of rows, where each row is a list of rainfall values for a day.
Note: This is intended as an exercise requiring the use of nested for loops, so you are not allowed to use the built-in sum function.

My current code is:

```
def print_daily_totals(rainfalls):
"""docstring for this function again"""
value = []
for (day, days_rain) in enumerate(rainfalls):
    print("Day {} total:".format(day))
    for rain in days_rain:
        print("{:-1}".format(rain))
```

However this doesnt lead to the rainfall being totalled it leads to the rainfall of that day being stated individually.

for example the correct answer is :

```
Day 0 total: 19
Day 1 total: 20
Day 2 total: 42
Day 3 total: 0
```

But I get:

```
Day 0 total:
0
9
3
7
Day 1 total:
11
9
0
0
Day 2 total:
0
10
12
20
Day 3 total:
0
0
0
0
```

How do I total the rainfall data without using the built in sum function?

Comment: You can use the build in [sum](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum) function, in any case use `sum(days_rain)`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I can't use the built in sum function

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output? The problem seems to be a little but unclear.

Comment: If you know `sum()` works, have you tried creating your own function that would take in a list and return sum of all items?

Answer (score 1):

Then recreate the sum yourself?

```py
def print_daily_totals(rainfalls):
"""docstring for this function again"""
for (day, days_rain) in enumerate(rainfalls):
    s = 0
    for rain in days_rain:
        s += rain
    print(f"Day {day} total: {s}")
```